# How do I create a namespaced element with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, podcast

I'm using lxml to generate an RSS feed that is ultimately used as a podcast. That means I need to add namespaced elements like `<itunes:duration>` and `<itunes:subtitle>`. But I'm having so much trouble trying to figure out how to create elements like these with lxml dynamically.

If I simply try:

```
from lxml import etree

element = etree.Element("itunes:duration")
```

I get this:

```
ValueError: Invalid tag name 'itunes:duration'
```

Next I tried this and got a little closer:

```
from lxml import etree

etree.register_namespace("itunes", "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd")
element = etree.Element("{itunes}duration")
print(etree.tostring(element).decode("utf-8"))
```

However that resulted in this output:

```
<ns0:duration xmlns:ns0="itunes"/>
```

So while that's better than an exception, it's still obviously not right. How can I create an element with an `itunes:` prefix in the tag name?

Comment: Did you try reading the lxml tutorial section about namespaces https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces - you can probably find many other sources of information on this topic by using a popular search engine with the search for: __lxml namespace__

Comment: @barny Yup and I couldn't make two cents of it. I was hoping someone had already done this and could provide a more concise code snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`etree.QName()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.QName-class.html)...

```py
from lxml import etree

etree.register_namespace("itunes", "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd")
element = etree.Element(etree.QName("http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd", "duration"))
print(etree.tostring(element).decode("utf-8"))
```

prints...

```xml
<itunes:duration xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"/>
```

You could also just use Clark notation...

```py
element = etree.Element("{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}duration")
```

Comment: This is great! Do you also happen to know if there's any way to strip the `xmlns:itunes` attribute from that?

Comment: @soapergem - No, I don't think so. If you strip it it's no longer [namespace well formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/317052). However, once you start combining elements to create your document the namespace declaration should only appear once when you serialize it.